# What tools do you use to aggregate your Internet activities?

Tags: rss, blogging, aggregation

With the explosion of the *Social Web* in the last couple of years, I find myself producing more and more narcissistic, inane, self congratulatory content all over the place.  What do you use to consolidate your various streams of awesomeness into a single font of wisdom?

Comment: This question makes me realize I am obviously not surfing this wave. I'm in the wading pool with my Facebook account.

Comment: On the contrary it probably means that you have a more agreeably sized ego ;).  Besides your contributions on SO,SU etc are certainly part of the Social Web explosion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a shadow of a doubt [Friendfeed](http://friendfeed.com/) and [Ping.Fm](http://ping.fm/) are the best tools for social mess, I mean media.

Comment: Ok,  I am biased towards this answer, it's what I use.  I am, however, genuinely interested in what other people use.

Comment: FriendFeed is great! I use it myself with great results.

Comment: FF gives me the irrits as it does not recognise when someone has their tweets going automatically to facebook and you just end up with duplicate messages all the time.

Comment: @evan, the hide feature is your friend.

Answer (score 5):

The [Jon Skeet Facts page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305223/jon-skeet-facts).

(Sorry, couldn't resist.)

As a more serious answer, I don't try to aggregate them at all at the moment. I use Google Reader for blogs but only blogs, Witty or the normal Twitter web page for Twitter, Google Groups for newsgroups, the "native" MSN, Skype and Google Talk clients for chat, and each of the SO-type sites separately. All horribly low tech, but I seem to get by.

I'm hoping that once Google Wave launches, that will consolidate things somewhat.

Comment: Agreed.  Looking forward to seeing what we can do with Wave.

Comment: Wow! Since you spend so much time on web, do you have time for any other things?

Comment: Sorry.  I'll get back to you on that one,  gotta go Tweet about my lunch.

Answer (score 2):

I think the kind of thing you're talking about is called [lifestreaming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lifestreaming).

You might want to check out [Chi.mp](http://chi.mp/) as one example.

Comment: Indeed it is.  Checking out Chim.mp.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

[Google Reader](http://reader.google.com) for all the gazillion RSS feeds out there.

Comment: I was more talking about something that takes a bunch of your own feeds (blog, twitter, stack overflow RSS, various feeds from other sites) and turns them into a single feed.

Answer (score 0):

I live in one of four applications, either on my Mac, iPhone or Windows:

iPhone:

- [TweetDeck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TweetDeck) - for Twitter
- FaceBook - Since TweetDeck on iPhone doesn't integrate.
- [NetNewsWire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetNewsWire) - RSS Feeds
- Mail - Duh :P
- Safari - Stack Overflow Trilogy

Mac OS X:

- TweetDeck - for Twitter and Facebook
- NetNewsWire - RSS Feeds
- Mail
- Safari - StackOverflow Trilogy

Windows:

- TweetDeck - for Twitter and Facebook
- [FeedDeamon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FeedDemon) - RSS Feeds
- Outlook
- Safari - Stack Overflow Trilogy

Anything more than this would be overkill.

Comment: Again, I was more interested in tools to take your own feeds and combine them into a single feed.  Not so much the consumption of feeds.

Comment: I have yet to find something that will bring all these into one, and will be following this closely. I will admit the line is very thin, since I consume my own stuff within all these applications.